# Is asking for useful programming metrics on-topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've had a question that is rather unusual, but that I still think is valuable for this community. Instead just discarding it, I've posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708734/how-many-times-per-second-can-you-increase-and-sum-all-numbers-in-a-big-array) and made this SO post to open a debate and justify why I think this way.

Mapping/reducing an array is a very generic operation that is widely used to implement all kinds of algorithms and computations. As such, it is often necessary for a programmer to **estimate** how much time it would take to complete a specific computation in specific dataset. Often, this boils down to implementing and testing. In the best case, it works. In the worst case, the programmer will realize he misestimated the task. He will then have to re-evaluate everything, possibly needing to port his code to another language or even architecture.

You might be aware of [latency numbers every programmer should know](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832). It is a small file with a big importance. It has been widely been used by programmers all around to estimate if a certain system will handle a task. Knowing a disk seek costs roughly 4 orders of magnitude more time than a memory seek, for example, might impact your decision to keep critical data memory cached in your web server, saving it from a huge waste of resources. A veteran programmer might know this from experience, but, for a newcomer, those numbers are insightful.

The purpose of this question is to aggregate information that can help us **estimating** the computational cost of a specific task, in the same vein of the file above.  I believe it is on topic because it is helpful for a community of developers trying to solve problems. I believe it isn't too broad because, while this could help a wide number of programmers solving different problems, the question itself has a well defined and limited. And I believe this is different from a "programming language contest" because I'm not asking for opinions or debate, but for numbers and data.

Is this point of view correct? What do you think?

Comment: That topic by itself is so broad and the context where and when these metrics apply so diverse that although interesting, it should be off-topic.

Comment: Okay then. That is a shame, it would be insightful IMO. I'll leave it open and let the community do whatever it judges the best with both threads. Thanks :)

Comment: IMHO no the question is not useful.  The question you asked essentially has no bound and we like boundaries.

Answer (score 4):

The way you've posed your request falls afoul of a rather fundamental tenet of Stack Exchange: [a question asking for a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124462/159251), "where every answer is equally valid", is not a good use of the features here.

Such a post makes voting and answer score pointless, and it fails what I would argue is *the* fundamental promise of this platform: you have a *problem* of some kind, you find a question that matches, and below it you find a *solution*, without having to pore through a thread of dozens of ancillary or unrelated posts.

While the information you want to collect may be useful, Stack Overflow isn't the right platform for hosting it.

Comment: Okay, that is a shame. Do you suggest any other platform?

Comment: I don't know. I suppose Github, like the document you linked.

Answer (score 1):

No disrespect at all to the OP, because I got the sense that he was making a legitimate effort to pose a question that he truly felt had *value*.  I would commend him for making that effort, and then for posting it on SO Meta for discussion.  Seriously, that's the kind of community-minded contribution that makes SO so great.

I saw the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708734/how-many-times-per-second-can-you-increase-and-sum-all-numbers-in-a-big-array) come up in the review queues, and my first reaction was that the question was very broad.  However, after thinking on it for just a bit, it occurs to me that simply opening the door to questions of this nature would be setting a precedent that would be difficult to manage in SO.

Using this method, I could see the explosion of questions for measuring performance of features between language/library versions, platforms (Mac vs Windows vs Linux, etc), architectures (e.g. i7 vs. i3 vs MIPS, etc), and even vendor models (MacBook 2015 vs iMac 2015 vs Mac Pro vs Mac Mini) or vendors (Mac vs Dell vs HP vs Lenovo vs THinkpad).

This seems to be far too fertile ground for so-called *rep whores* to create (possibly many series of) arbitrary questions to artificially increase their rep scores.  And then the burden of the effort to deal with that explosion of new questions and answers would be borne on reviewers, moderators, and the site itself.

Honestly, I don't see any legitimately useful outcome to this form of question on this site, regardless of how much I'd actually *like to know* the performance of various features / techniques based on properly-written benchmarks.

I do see this as a particularly useful type of *answer*, notably when you have multiple competing answers that have no other discerning differences beyond style.  I've given a few such answers here on SO (please be gentle):

- [Ruby - is efficient way to find the difference between two very large arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37356456/6263819)
- [obj.nil? vs. obj == nil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37287459/6263819)
- [How to split string using regex to split between +,-,*,/ symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37379731/6263819)
- [Ruby function to remove all white spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37087697/6263819)

I do a fair amount of benchmarking in my own environment, and sometimes the results are truly surprising for commonly-used language features; this is typically when I post my benchmarks as answers.

Still, I don't see this as a suitable sort of question; the conditions vary too significantly to be able to compare benchmarks across machines to be able to draw any useful conclusions from multiple answers submitted from random community members.  It takes a great deal of care to write benchmarks that are simply *adequate*, and a great deal more time and effort to write benchmarks that are actually *good*.

Soliciting benchmarks from the broader community may be the "first question from a new user" experience substantially compounded by the number of potential benchmarks that they would contribute.  It's hard enough teaching new users how to write a useful question, but teaching the whole community how to write useful benchmarks seems *so much harder*.

So, I would vote to close the door on this type of question before anyone has a chance to become accustomed to it.

And to the OP, I would suggest that you keep pushing the boundaries, even if the ideas aren't always accepted, because one *really good* idea can be a game-changer.

Answer (score -3):

> Mapping/reducing an array is a very generic operation that is widely used to implement all kinds of algorithms and computations.

**This benchmark does *not* actually have wide applicability to other situations**.

For small arrays, the time taken depends very strongly on whether or not the data is already hot in cache.  Different algorithms will have different access patterns, leading to different cache miss rates.  e.g. something with many different small arrays scattered around will do much worse than something with one small array that it touches often (and crucially, no large data structures that it touches in between, leading to eviction of the small array.)

**The time to "loop over and modify an array of 100 ints" in a real program (not a microbenchmark doing *only* that) depends strongly on factors external to that task**.  Even if people thought survey / benchmark result collection questions were ok, this one is badly designed.

---

To learn more about how to predict the performance of code running on an x86 CPU, see the links in [SO's x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), especially [Agner Fog's microarchiture pdf](http://agner.org/optimize/), and vendor optimization manuals.

Benchmarks in very high level languages will depend very strongly on the interpreter / JIT compiler.

Comment: Did you mean to post this on the SO question?

Comment: @Mysticial: It's an explanation of why this specific question is crap, because the gathered data isn't as useful as the OP is hoping.  I think it belongs on meta.